# How to reduce size of CakePDF

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. In a project, I am using CakePdf to generate & download pdf files, from my db data.

Now, what is my problem is, I saw CakePdf is 54.5 MB. I think its a little big. So, is there any way to reduce the size ? I am using `DomPDF` as the `engine`, so can I delete other engines ? If so, which files & folders should I delete ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are ~55mb on a disk a problem in 2014?

Comment: No, no problem, I was just thinking to delete the unnecessary things from there, that's it. @burzum

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the other engines under the plugin's `/Vendor` folder gaining around 40MB space.

You could also remove `/Pdf/Engine` files for those engines but it won't save you more than a few hundred bytes so don't bother.